# 2 default gateways, one to 0.0.0.0... with DHCP

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, networking, dhcp, routing

A problem that I have here with Windows 7 (RTM) and Windows Vista (SP2), on multiple machines, is that clients get a default gateway of the DHCP server (like they should) but on top of that, also a default gateway to 0.0.0.0.

This only happens when the computer starts up, not after I do a /release and /renew or when I run from an elevated command prompt: "route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0".

DHCP is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 (RTM) (2 servers with split scopes), machines have different network adapters (one is a Marvel Yukon, the other a Realtek) and all drivers are up-to-date, including the drivers on the servers.

Any suggestions?