# PC gets 2 gateways after networking issue

Tags: networking

I'm currently testing a 10 gig ethernet capable network setup with a DIY router running Kea for DHCP. I've not been able to replicate the circumstances where I'd caused this but during testing a raspberry pi (which does up to 100mbps) on my switch, I ended up having some unusual DHCP issues.

My network topology, for the moment looks a little like this

[image]

Aurora is my desktop - and I'm using the onboard gigabit to connect to my 'legacy' network (upstream internet) and the 10 gigabit router. Due to 10 gig interfaces having a lower metric it will always connect first The router has one 10 gig port connected to the upstream, and one to a switch to which client devices are connected. The PC has a reserved IP on the DHCP server and will always get the same IP based on the MAC address of the interface.

While I've not been able to replicate the issue - after plugging in a freshly set up raspberry pi, the entire 10gig network setup went down. At some point through working through the various components of the router it fixed itself. While I forgot to document the checks I did, the router *was* able to connect to the upstream through these troubles. My PC wasn't able to connect out to the internet *or* to the router, despite getting an IP from it.

While its a similar issue to [this older post](https://superuser.com/questions/46419/2-default-gateways-one-to-0-0-0-0-with-dhcp) - I'm able to connect *if* I set my IP and default gateway manually. I didn't take screenshots but the router *was* able to connect out, there were no changes in the settings of the DHCP server (kea) or firewall

The Kea subnet block looks like this

```
    "subnet4": [
        {
            // This defines the whole subnet. Kea will use this information to
            // determine where the clients are connected. This is the whole
            // subnet in your network.

            // Subnet identifier should be unique for each subnet.
            "id": 1,

            // This is mandatory parameter for each subnet.
            "subnet": "10.0.0.1/24",

            // Pools define the actual part of your subnet that is governed
            // by Kea. Technically this is optional parameter, but it's
            // almost always needed for DHCP to do its job. If you omit it,
            // clients won't be able to get addresses, unless there are
            // host reservations defined for them.
            "pools": [ { "pool": "10.0.0.51 - 10.0.0.200" } ],

            // These are options that are subnet specific. In most cases,
            // you need to define at least routers option, as without this
            // option your clients will not be able to reach their default
            // gateway and will not have Internet connectivity.
            "option-data": [
                {
                    // For each IPv4 subnet you most likely need to specify at
                    // least one router.
                    "name": "routers",
                    "data": "10.0.0.1"
                }


            ],
```

The PC is on roughly as simple a reservation block as possible

```
                {
                    "hw-address": "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF",
                    "ip-address": "10.0.0.50"
                },
```

The one odd thing out was this

[image]

Which resulted in any attempt to connect out failing as it was trying to connect to a non existent default gateway, and one that hadn't been configured anywhere. This doesn't have anything to do with routes at all. During previous experimentation I found out that you can't even set up 2 default gateways on a subnet intentionally - so this is unusual, I couldn't actually ssh into the router either via 10.0.0.1 and ended up using its upstream IP to test.

I *was* able to get the system running by setting a static IP with the correct default gateway - and subsequently the problem seemed to self resolved. During the period, I re-set the firewall settings and restarted DHCP, so I'm unsure what is the exact fix.

Why *would* a system get a non existent default gateway from DHCP, and how would one 'properly' fix that?

Comment: Is it possible that that's exactly what the DHCP lease from Kea offered? (Were you trying to add a "Classless static routes" option or something?)

Comment: Nope! I checked through the config - which ... has not changed since I got it working other than adding reservations.  I hadn't been tweaking the configuration at that point.  I've added a partial configuration, and its been the same config so far. Unless there's some 'hidden' reason its offering 0.0.0.0, it shouldn't